# Safari won't play HTML5/JS embedded audio (MediaElement.js)

Tags: javascript, html, audio, safari, mediaelement.js

Having trouble getting HTML5 audio to play in Safari. Works in IE, Chrome, Firefox.

I have both an MP3 and OGG embedded in my code (tried swapping both just in case, still nothing).

I'm using the MediaElement.js HTML5 audio player. My js is fine.

I have setup MIME types in my .htaccess - nothing.

Any ideas?

(Also not playing on iOS devices as well)

Comment: Do you have set the MIME type like this:`AddType audio/mpeg .mp3`? Does the file play in the browser window when you call it directly?

Comment: I had them setup as follows: `AddType video/ogg .ogv` `AddType video/mp4 .mp4` --- then clearly noticed _"video"_ so switched to _"audio"_ (still nothing), then changed _mp4_ > _mp3_ (nada) and _ogg_ to _.ogg_ (still nothing) –

Comment: When I call it directly - Safari shows me a "loading" Quicktime (?) widget and does not load it - at all.

Comment: Seems that the file is corrupt or maybe in a format that's not compatible. Can you try this with another `.mp3` file?

Comment: File is def not corrupt. Plays in all other browsers but Safari.

Comment: That's strange. Is this online somewhere? Could you share a link?

Comment: Fixed it... MIME types weren't correct, correct MIME types:

`AddType audio/mpeg .mp3`
`AddType audio/ogg .ogg`

Comment: Isn't that what I said in my first comment? ;)